# RBAC in Yii2 with PhpManager

Tags: yii2, rbac

How can I implement `RBAC` in `Yii 2.0` without any database. 
I will have just 2 roles , i.e. `admin and author` .
my RbacController is

```
<?php
namespace app\commands;

use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;

class RbacController extends Controller
{
    public function actionInit()
    {
        $auth =  \Yii::$app->authManager;

        // add "createPost" permission
        $createPost = $auth->createPermission('createPost');
        $createPost->description = 'Create a post';
        $auth->add($createPost);

        // add "updatePost" permission
        $updatePost = $auth->createPermission('updatePost');
        $updatePost->description = 'Update post';
        $auth->add($updatePost);

        // add "author" role and give this role the "createPost" permission
        $author = $auth->createRole('author');
        $auth->add($author);
        $auth->addChild($author, $createPost);

        // add "admin" role and give this role the "updatePost" permission
        // as well as the permissions of the "author" role
        $admin = $auth->createRole('admin');
        $auth->add($admin);
        $auth->addChild($admin, $updatePost);
        $auth->addChild($admin, $author);

        // Assign roles to users. 1 and 2 are IDs returned by IdentityInterface::getId()
        // usually implemented in your User model.
        $auth->assign($author, 2);
        $auth->assign($admin, 1);
    }
}
```

I am getting an error

```
  `PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function createPermission() 
on a non-object in var/www/commands/RbacController.php on line 14
    PHP Fatal Error 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Call to a member
 function createPermission() on a non-object' in /var/www/commands/RbacController.php:14
```

while executing `yii rbac/init` . I am using basic template with PhpManager .  I have added `'authManager' => [ 'class' => 'yii\rbac\PhpManager', ],` in web.php .I am using basic template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official documentation actually uses a php file https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/security-authorization.md

Comment: post your RbacController

Answer (score 10):

i Know this is a bit old, but I want to publish the solution.. at least what worked for me.

> I have added 'authManager' => [ 'class' => 'yii\rbac\PhpManager', ],
>   in web.php

There is the mistake, since you a re running the command via console, you need to add that same line in the components section of console.php (in the same directory as web.php).

I hope this helps others who have a similar problem :D

Comment: Or add it to the common configuration main.php so it will be available to all apps.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your controller

```
$auth = new \yii\rbac\PhpManager();
 // add "createPost" permission
$createPost = $auth->createPermission('createPost');
$createPost->description = 'Create a post';
$auth->add($createPost);
```

http://blog.dedikisme.com/blog/2014/05/09/rpbac-yii2-framework